# Comparing 2 elements in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So I'm trying to compare the row/col location of 2 elements to see if they're adjacent. After a lot of searching I could not find what I was looking for on similar questions on SO.

Anyways, my main question is just in regards to the syntax on one of my lines of code. So here's what I have:

```
 private boolean adjacent(int row, int col) 
{
  boolean adjacent = true;
  Dot d2 = gameArray[row][col];
  Descriptor D2 = new Descriptor (row, col, d2);
  Descriptor D1 = list.get(list.size()-1);

  if (D1.row() == D2.row() && D1.col() == D2.col() +1) {
      adjacent = true;
  }
  return adjacent;
}
```

Basically what I'm looking at is the `if` row. I want to keep it simple and check if the `col` location of element D2 is +/- 1. So I wanted to use absolute value, but not as an ArrayList method, just something simple like `|1|` or something.

How would I implement that to the `== D2.col()` part of the `if` statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
if (Math.abs(D1.row() - D2.row()) + Math.abs(D1.col() - D2.col()) == 1)
```

The sum of two non-negative integers is 1 if and only if exactly one of them is equal to 1 and the other is equal to zero, precisely what you want.

EDIT: now that I read your question more carefully, I realize that you do not consider two elements adjacent if they are in the same column in adjacent rows. Then the statement is even simpler:

```
if (D1.row() == D2.row() && Math.abs(D1.col() - D2.col()) == 1)
```

Comment: So that works for both left and right of an element as well as above and below?

Comment: btw, THEY ARE considered adjacent if they are in the same column in adjacent rows. Basically they're considered adjacent if an element is directly above, below, left, or right of another. Only diagonals do not count as adjacent.

Comment: In that case the first line in my answer will work. If two elements are adjacent, either `abs` of their xs or `abs` of their ys is equal to one, and the other is equal to zero (because diagonals are not adjacent), and so the sum of those `abs`s is equal to one -- exactly what that line of code checks.